# MVC Html.DropDownListFor returns complex type with null values

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have the following controller create action in my controller. It takes care that the displayname in the select list will be 'StoreName - StoreAddress'. The Store complexType is stored in Store.

```
        // GET: Purchases/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Stores = db.Stores.Select(s => new { DisplayName = s.StoreName.ToString() + " - " + s.Address.ToString(), Store = s});

            return View();
        }
```

In the Create View the following code takes care that it will be displayed correctly.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Store.StoreName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Store.StoreName, new SelectList(ViewBag.Stores, "Store", "DisplayName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Store.StoreName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

It will go to the post method of the controller (if I am correct).

```
        // POST: Purchases/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Store,Price,Date")] Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Store store = purchase.Store;

                db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(purchase);
        }
```

However the Store store = purchase.Store will now give a complex Store type with the values for anything other than StoreName set to null. StoreName will be a string.

How can I get a complex type returned that is equal to the selected Store object?

---

Edit 1:

```
public class Purchase
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public Store Store { get; set; }

       public string Type { get; set; }

       [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
       [Column(TypeName = "money")]
       public decimal Price { get; set; }

       [DataType(DataType.Date)]
       [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
       public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   }

public class PurchaseDBContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {

       }
   }
```

```
public class Store
    {
        public int StoreId { get; set; }

        public string StoreName { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^((\+|00(\s|\s?\-\s?)?)31(\s|\s?\-\s?)?(\(0\)[\-\s]?)?|0)[1-9]((\s|\s?\-\s?)?[0-9])((\s|\s?-\s?)?[0-9])((\s|\s?-\s?)?[0-9])\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "This is not a valid phonenumber")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    }
```

Do I need to use additional annotations to set the navigation properties?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using an ORM like EF. Have you setup navigation properties for Purchase and Store entities?

Comment: I have set the classes Purchase and Store in the post. Do I need to set additional navigation properties (like [Key] and [ForeignKey("Store")])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's alot going on in your example, but there isn't a need to pass a complex object if you're using Navigation Properties and your model is setup in a certain way. If you setup a navigation property for Store/StoreId, Entity Framework should infer things for you, so it will simplify your view.

```
public class Purchase 
{
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StoreId")]
    public Store Store { get; set;}
}
```

I'd pass a model to the view similar to below. IMO, it's cleaner than using ViewBag.

```
public class CreatePurchaseModel
{
    //To populate a list
    public List<Store> AvailableStores { get; set; }
    //The actual object to be created
    public Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
// GET: Purchases/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new CreatePurchaseModel() 
    {
        AvailableStores = db.Stores.ToList(),
        Purchase = new Purchase()
    };

    return View(vm);     
}
```

Populate a dropdownlist with the AvailableStores property to set the Purchase.StoreId

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Purchase.StoreId, Model.AvailableStores.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.StoreName.ToString(), Value = x.StoreId.ToString() }))
```

If it's setup properly, all you need in the post method parameters is the purchase

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken, HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Purchase purchase) 
{
    //purchase.StoreId should have a non zero value
    db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```